# build.gradle file stuck at loading in Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

[image: Stuck Here]

`build.gradle` file shows if I `invalidate caches / restart` in android studio. After that, it opens for once and then stuck at the same screen. I am not able to figure out what causes this and how would I get rid of it.
Android Studio v2.3.3.

Comment: Anything change to bring this on? Did you recently upgrade AS?

Comment: I just checked the recently installed plugins and found one plugin name `Android Method Counts` related to Gradle file. Disabled it and worked.